# Git on windows: how to get pre-receive hook to run on the server using a file share

Tags: git, githooks

Unfortunately I have to run git on Windows.

I am sharing the git repository using a windows share (e.g. //ip address/GitRepo.git)

The problem is that git seems to treat this as a local path and runs the pre-receive hook on the client!

e.g. if my pre-receive hook consists of something along the lines of:

```
echo $(ls /C)
```

then I see the contents of the client C drive and not the server

How do I get the pre-receive hook to run on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind. Just use SSH rather than a windows share

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer, as it is the correct one.